# how to connect SPSS with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, connection, spss, database

I have mongodb where my data is stored.

I am using SPSS where I have do some data analysis.

Can someone help me in connecting SPSS to mongodb.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SPSS Modeler or Statistics? In both cases you can access MongoDB using R. Both Statistics and Modeler have integration with R. So you can just use the R package 'rmongodb' and connect to your MongoDB.

Here you have some links:

https://docs.compose.io/languages/r.html

http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-mongodb/

Remember to use R with Statistics you need to install the plugin 'IBM SPSS Statistics - Essentials for R'

ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/20.0/en/rplugin/InstallationDocuments/Windows/Essentials_for_R_Installation_Instructions.pdf

If you are using IBM SPSS Modeler, you need to install the plugin 'IBM SPSS Modeler - Essentials for R'

ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/analyticserver/1.0/English/IBM_SPSS_Modeler_Essentials_for_R_Installations_Instructions.pdf

There are two articles on DeveloperWorks (one wrote by me) were I explain how to start working with R and SPSS...

-Create new nodes for IBM SPSS modeler 16 using R:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-spssmodeler16-r-nodes/index.html

-Calling R from SPSS: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-call-r-spss/index.html