# What is the recommended way to create a consolidated data store for large SPSS files that have survey data (having 600–800 columns)?

Tags: mongodb, spss, survey

Hello Everyone I just need your suggestion what is the best way to store the data retrieving from SPSS file and storing into Mongo db or RDBMS or any other .
The data comprises of responses to survey questionnaire which can span upto large number of columns (600-800) depending on the number of questions and other attributes recorded for the respondent and the survey study.  Also these surveys are conducted periodically - however it's not necessary that the questions remain exactly the same - these may vary from survey to survey.

The need is to consolidate this data into a uniform structure and enable further analysis over the consolidated data spanning over multiple survey for which again the plan is to use SPSS.

One option I considered was to store data in MongoDB as then there is flexibility on how the schema can be modified across surveys i.e. rigid schema definition part can be avoided. However in this case not sure if SPSS would support working against Mongo

Would be very interested to know if someone has had any experience in this area or could provide some suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to connect SPSS with mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804610/how-to-connect-spss-with-mongodb)

Comment: Since SPSS does not need to store all of the data in ram, there often isn't any specific need for a database structure at the back end. How many survey's are you talking about? As far as the questions changing, you will need to normalize the fields somehow to conduct data analysis in the end in SPSS, so that is a somewhat different concern. Most agencies I am aware of just have different flat files for each set of questions (which would be close to equivalent to a traditional relational database).

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy w for your quick response.Actually i am having around 30-40 SPSS file .yeah you are absolutely right we have normalize somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider, if you plan to create generalized jobs that can be run over surveys that are similar but differ in details is to set up a classification system for the variables such as demographic, opinion, economic etc, and assign these using custom attributes when the sav files are created.  You can then use these attributes in generalized jobs to determine what to do based on generic properties rather than tying the code to specific variable names.

You can use the SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES to define macros based on variable properties, including custom attributes and then use those macros in your syntax in place of specific variable names.

We have seen that an approach like this can dramatically reduce the number of different but similar jobs that an organization has to otherwise maintain.

Comment: Hi JKP,Thanks a lot for your feedback .Actually right now i was thinking to read SPSS with the help of R  retrieving the useful information like question in one table and answer in another table like so on ..and storing into either Oracle or Mongodb?Can you please tell me this is the right approach to do or else if possible plz suggest as your experience.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you want to do.  You can read data files including their metadata with either Python or R, although the Python apis have somewhat more functionality.  Another extension command that you might find helpful is GATHERMD.  It takes a wildcard specification for a set of files and directories and builds a dataset containing all the variable names, file names, and selected custom attributes that you could then use for indexing or other purposes.  Besides sav files, it also supports SAS and Stata files.

Comment: Hi JKP..can we have one to one mail discussion plz if possible or else tell me how can i reach you personally to discuss something

Comment: My email is peck AT us.ibm.com

Comment: I wrote it that way to perhaps reduce slightly the number of spammer scans that would pick it up.